# How to get unique strings from array c++

Tags: c++, string, sorting, unique

i know my question can be stupid for somebody, but i googled all day and try make my own solution but i failed.. Please help..

I need print all uniqe string from an simple array of strings.

example:

input: "Hi" "my" "name" "Hi" "potato" "text" "name" "Hi"

output: "my" "potato" "text"

I make  just function to print everything once ("Hi", "my", "name", "potato", "text"), but i need ignore everything what is 2x and more times in array.

My algorythm was:
 1. sort by bubblesort

2. print only last string from sorted sequence by using basic for and if

.. if(array[i]!=array[i+1]) //make something...

Comment: You could use an unordered map (aka hash table). The strings are the key and the count is the data. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update : i was misunderstanding the question now it works as output in the question
simply you can count the occurrences of every string and print only strings which occur ones..
time complexity : O(N^2)
here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n; // number of strings you want in your array
    cin >> n;
    string t; // get t and push back it in the vector
    vector <string> words; //we use vector to store  as we will push back them
    for(size_t i = 1;i <= n;i++)
    {
        cin >> t;
        words.push_back(t);

    }
    for(int i = 0;i < words.size();i++)
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        for(int j = 0;j < words.size() && cnt < 2;j++)
        {
            if(words[i] == words[j])
                cnt++;
        }
        if(cnt == 1) //its unique..print it
            cout << words[i] <<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thaks but  this isnt it.. my problem is different... i need completely ignore all strings in array which is 2 or more times in array... 

So, print only unique strings from array.

Again example: input: "hi" "hello" "hi" and output is only "hello" becouse it is only 1 time in array...

Comment: see my update answer @Jiri Hlavik and sorry for misunderstanding .

Comment: Although the code does work correctly, I'd like to strongly suggest sticking to using STL algorithms for these type of loop-heavy tasks, as they are far less error-prone and much more readable!

Comment: @Brian Rodriguez I don't understand you what is specifically part in the code you refer to ?

Comment: The for loops you've used could be replaced by functions in the `<algorithm>` header.  See my answer for examples

Comment: what the time complexity for your code in worst case  ?

Comment: @stark my time complexity is O(nlgn), the sort being the most expensive operation

Comment: You could avoid excess iterations once you've already proven a word is not unique by changing the check in the nested loop to break out when cnt is 2. for (int j = 0; cnt < 2 && j < words.size(); j++)

Comment: @Brian Rodriguez , your code is better in large input sizes (y) and easy to be understood the concept is mine is easier to be used for medium ones as its trivial :) (y)

Comment: @Justin Ryder good notice bro, i will edit the code to be terminated once count > 1

Comment: Mines only 5 lines long (not including whitespace). Do I win the Internet?

Comment: @stark yes, but those things you've mentioned are what matters most for good programming practices, especially when you want to be 100% sure that the code will, and always will, work correctly.  Always prefer the STL!

Comment: One day we'll have ranges and this'll be a one-liner :(

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<std::string> v = {
        "Hi", "my", "name", "Hi", "potato", "text", "name", "Hi",
    };

    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (auto a = v.begin(), b = a; a != v.end(); a = b) {
        b = find_if(b, v.end(), [&](string s) {return *b != s;});
        if (distance(a, b) == 1)
                cout << *a << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words{"Hi", "my", "name", "Hi", "potato", "text", "name", "Hi"};

    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    for (auto curr = words.begin(); curr != words.end(); ) {
        // If working w/ few duplicate words:
        auto next = std::find_if(
            curr + 1, words.end(), [&](const auto& s) { return s != *curr; }
            );
        /* If working w/ many duplicate words:
        auto next = std::upper_bound(curr + 1, words.end(), *curr); */
        if (std::distance(curr, next) == 1) {
            std::cout << *curr++ << '\n';
        } else {
            curr = next;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4459c9e3806ff62b)

---

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound),   [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_if),   [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

Comment: @graham I considered it, but that'd do all the work I need done without actually singling out the elements that matter, so I opted to do the work myself.

Comment: Don't understand. `unique_copy` does exactly what is needed. Added my answer.

Comment: `unique_copy` copies the first element of each sub-range of equal elements.  The OP is asking to gather the elements that only occur once in the range.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words{"Hi", "my", "name", "Hi", "potato", "text", "name", "Hi"};
    std::vector<std::string> out;

    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    std::unique_copy(words.begin(), words.end(), std::back_inserter(out));
    std::set_difference(words.begin(), words.end(), out.begin(), out.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Note: Not tested as I am writing this on my phone and in bed.

Comment: You can cut out the `out` vector and just `std::unique_copy` straight to the `std::ostream_iterator`!  Also, the OP wants words that appear exactly once, so extra work is required after the unique_copy

Comment: If you go this route of using `unique_copy`, you'll have to use `set_difference` to find the duplicates then the take the `set_difference` between those sets to find the single-occurring items.

Comment: or erase/remove from the uniques based on the element counts.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez Ah yes. You are right. I thought that `unique_copy` returned those that were listed once.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i,j;
string ss;
cin>>ss;
 for(i=0;i<ss.length();i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<ss.length();j++)
    {
     if(ss[i]==ss[j]&&i!=j)
       {
        ss[i]=' ';
       }
    }
}
    for(i=0;i<ss.length();i++)
{
    if(ss[i]!=' ')cout<<ss[i]<<" ";  /// for unique element print
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
int a[n],i,j,k;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>a[i];
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<n;j++)
    {
     if(a[i]==a[j]&&i!=j)
       {
        a[i]=0;
       }
    }
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(a[i]!=0)cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}
```

}

Comment: The question is about `string`s, not `int`s. Also, why do you post two answers? That aside, code-only answers are not terribly helpful. It encourages people to copy & paste from the web instead of learning how to dot his. Can you [edit] the answer you want to keep and explain the code?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).